# Probability of a coin toss six times resulting in three heads and three tails

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability that a coin tossed six times results in three heads and three tails (in any order)? I am not sure how to count this using permutations and combinations. The complement does not seem reasonable to solve either, and the problem should not use advanced casework.

Comment: Show your work.  How many sequences of letters $H,T$ are there of length $6$?  What is the probability of each?  How many of them consist of three $H$ and three $T$?  Is that a permutation or combination?

Comment: It should be a combination, right? And how would I count the number of sequences of letters H, T there are of length 6 that consist of three H and T? That is my question.

Comment: Good to remember: $\frac 1 {2^{2n}}\binom n{2n}=\frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi n}}(1-\frac {c_n}n)$ for $\frac 1 9<c_n<\frac 1 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly $\color\red3$ heads in $\color\green6$ tosses is:

$$\binom{\color\green6}{\color\red3}\cdot\left(\frac{\color\red3}{\color\green6}\right)^{\color\red3}\cdot\left(1-\frac{\color\red3}{\color\green6}\right)^{\color\green6-\color\red3}$$

Comment: So that would be the answer? Did you count the prob. of getting the 3 tails too?

Comment: @DiscreteMath: Is there any way to toss a coin $6$ times, get $3$ heads and a different number of tails?????

Comment: Examine barak's formula carefully.  Figure out what each factor is for.

Comment: I ought to change that "rolls" to "tosses" though...